# How to fix dependencies duplicate error on Android studio Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

Hello, current I develop use flutter & Dart on Android studio.

but when I try build. always occur message and build fail.

first I judged AndroidX problem.
so I try change code refer https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

`android/gradle.properties`

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

and changed `android/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and I write command `gradlew build`

but it is not solve.

How to fix this problem?

thanks.

Comment: just try to delete `.iml` file from your project and try to rebuild

Answer (score 0):

You can have a dependencies report with the gradlew command dependencie like this :

```
gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies_report.txt
```

This task will report all dependencies in your project and export to a file in the root of your project,
Then from there you can search for duplicate group/module and use 'exclude' in your gradle if/where needed