# Duplicate classes from jetified-aws-android-sdk and jetified-aws-java-sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, netcdf4

I have an Android app that explicitly uses the latest (v2.15.+) version of Amazon's AWS library, but it also has a dependency on an ungodly huge library (netcdf4) that appears to be pulling in its own (old) copy (v1.11.236) of Amazon's non-Android Java library and causing "Duplicate class" errors when building.

I know I need to somehow modify build.gradle so it uses the old (v1.11.236) version only for things pulled in by `implementation group: 'edu.ucar', name: 'netcdf4', version: '4.6.11'`, but uses the *new* (v2.15.+) version for everything else... but I'm not sure how to actually ***do*** that.

#### Things I've Tried so far:

Inspired by the answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027250/how-to-resolve-duplicate-class-error-in-gradle-build), I tried adding the following to the end of the "android{}" block (in the hope that it would unceremoniously strip out the non-Android .jars and allow everything to compile without errors).

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.getRuntimeConfiguration().exclude group: 'com.amazonaws', module: 'aws-java-sdk-core'
}
```

... unfortunately, it caused the Gradle sync to fail:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

### My current build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pantherkitty.launchspotter"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://artifacts.unidata.ucar.edu/repository/unidata-all/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:logger:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.15.+'
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.15.+@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.15.+@aar') { transitive = true }

    implementation group: 'edu.ucar', name: 'netcdf4', version: '4.6.11'

}
```

### ... and the errors:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\src\Android\launchspotter

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
(...snip...)
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AbortedException found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException$ErrorType found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.236)
(...snip...)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMS found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-kms-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-kms:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-kms-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-kms:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:1.11.236)
(...snip...)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3 found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-s3-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-s3-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$1 found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-s3-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$2 found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-s3-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Encryption found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-s3-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.236)
(...snip...)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.TimingInfoFullSupport found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.TimingInfoUnmodifiable found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.ValidationUtils found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.XMLWriter found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.XmlUtils found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.236)
  Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.XpathUtils found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.15.2.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.236.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.236)



BUILD FAILED in 594ms
17 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 16 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question as asked, you would do something like the following:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation('edu.ucar:netcdf4:4.6.11') {
    exclude group: 'com.amazonaws', module: 'aws-java-sdk-s3'
  }
}
```

That will exclude the `aws-java-sdk-s3` dependency from the old `netcdf-java` artifact. Unfortunately, version 2 of the AWS SDK isn't necessarily compatible with version 1 of the AWS SDK, so this will likely not work if any of the netcdf-java code needs to use any of the AWS SDK code. The good news is that netCDF-Java is now on version 5.3.2, and it uses version 2 of the AWS SDK.

Secondly, are you trying to write netCDF-4 files? If not, then you do not need the `netcdf4` artifact. Depending on your goal, you may only need the `cdm-core` artifact (which will allow you to read HDF4/5, netCDF3/4 files locally, or data from remote protocols like DAP2, cdmremote, etc.). For more information on the various artifacts, please see https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-java/current/userguide/using_netcdf_java_artifacts.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now! I'm actually only using NetCDF to parse GOES-16 satellite data. I'm using that particular artifact because it's one that I've successfully gotten to work with Android. As you might or might not know, NetCDF-Java is a BEAST when it comes to getting it to work with Android. Prior to ~2016, it didn't work at all due to AWT dependencies (among other things). Then, someone figured out how to get Android Studio to compile it, only to have Dalvik choke on > 65k references. Then, it made the .apk bigger than Google Play allowed. It finally became viable ~2018.

Comment: We've do not use netCDF-Java on Android ourselves, so we've never encountered the issue directly, although we have heard about the limitation on the number of class references. We have refactored our artifacts considerably over the past year, and `cdm-core` is all you need to read netCDF-4 files for GOES-16/17 data.

Comment: FYI, I tried switching to cdm-core, but now GridDataset.open(file) is blowing up. I opened an issue at Github at https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-java/issues/308 , in case you have any insight into the problem or can mention it to the right person over there. Thanks!