# Getting rid of Duplicate class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependencies, google-calendar-api

I'm building an android app and I'm trying to implement the Google Calendar API. However, when I add the dependencies code I get the error shown below. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this error? I've also inserted a picture of my dependencies in my build gradle below.

Side note: here is the need API dependencies code
`implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0' implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0' implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev305-1.23.0'`

[Dependencies picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI2or.png)

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Lya.png)

Comment: Maybe this post will help:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017459/duplicate-classes-from-jetified-aws-android-sdk-and-jetified-aws-java-sdk>

Comment: I tried no good. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by excluding some of the classes from the build Gradle. I just excluded the class that was causing the error.

```
implementation ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    exclude group:'com.google.guava'
}
implementation ('com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    exclude group:'com.google.guava'
}
implementation  ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev305-1.23.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    exclude group:'com.google.guava'
}
```

This Fixed my error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Google calendar api documentation:https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java

Maybe go back and forth between what you have and what's on here and check if there's anything different.