# Duplicate class found i module

Tags: java, android, http, jar

```
Duplicate class org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient found in modules jetified-ipp-v3-java-devkit-5.0-jar-with-dependencies.2-jar-with-dependencies 
(com.intuit.quickbooks-online:ipp-v3-java-devkit:5.0.2) and
 jetified-oauth2-platform-api-5.0-jar-with-dependencies.2-jar-with-dependencies 
(com.intuit.quickbooks-online:oauth2-platform-api:5.0.2)
```

Getting above error

I have tried

```
1.configurations {
    runtime.exclude group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', module: 'ipp-v3-java-devkit'
}
2. configurations {
    implementation.exclude group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', module: 'ipp-v3-java-devkit'
}
```

but no luck till yet

Comment: Try what's suggested here: [How to resolve duplicate class error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027250/how-to-resolve-duplicate-class-error-in-gradle-build)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve duplicate class error in gradle build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027250/how-to-resolve-duplicate-class-error-in-gradle-build)